# Nest - Search path

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to use the Nest client to consume an Elasticsearch instance.

However, the `/_search` endpoint is in fact `/search`.

Is there any possible way to change the behavior of the client to reflect this change?

I have tried looking into the source code but just can't figure out a way this can be done.

Disclaimer: I have no control over the ES instance, neither I know if there is some sort of proxy in the middle that alters the `/_search` into `/search`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to use `/search` endpoint to do search requests? From what I know only `/_search` one is valid. Maybe I missed point of your question.

Comment: Yes, `/_search` in my case does not exist. However, `/search` does.

Answer (score 0):

`/search` is not an API endpoint in Elasticsearch. It is not possible to change the API endpoints within the client, without changing the API specs from which it is generated and recompiling.

You *can* use the low level client's `DoRequest` and `DoRequestAsync` methods to call
a non-standard API

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();
    
var request = new SearchRequest<LogMessage>
{
    Query = new MatchQuery
    {
        Field = Infer.Field<LogMessage>(f => f.Level),
        Query = "warning"
    }
};
    
var response = client.LowLevel.DoRequest<SearchResponse<LogMessage>>(
    Elasticsearch.Net.HttpMethod.POST, 
    "/search", 
    PostData.Serializable<ISearchRequest>(request)
);
```